# How to make a new file with the windows context menu

Tags: batch-file, registry, contextmenu

Using the registry I used the following code below to create a sub-menu in the windows context menu.

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DesktopBackground\Shell\Power Menu]
"MUIVerb"="Matt's Usefull Tools"
"SubCommands"="batmode;logoff;switch;sleep;hibernate;restart;safemode;shutdown;hybridshutdown"
"Icon"="C:\\Users\\Matthew\\Downloads\\Hacker.ico"
"Position"="bottom"
```

Now I want to be able to click a command I set and then have it create a .bat file where I right clicked, I know you can add this to the "New" sub menu by editing the ".bat" registry using the code.

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bat\ShellNew]
 "NullFile"=""
```

Now is it possible to implement this into my sub-menu?

Answer (score 1):

i could get this only to work w/ following command:
CMD.exe /c @ECHO.>"%V\New File.bat"

Under HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\Shell\batfile\command

where "batfile" must be one of your "SubCommands".

the issue is, that this will always create the "New File.bat" in current location (e.g. Desktop). 
If there's an existing "New File.bat" it will just overwrite it.
If you use CMD.exe /c @ECHO.>>"%V\New File.bat" and there's an existing copy of "New File.bat", it will just add whitespace to the file.

i do not know a way to Call "ShellNew" from "command". :/

Maybe it helps anyway.

Edit: 
whoops... just saw that this is an one year old question ^.^
anyway - it may help somebody else. :)